# How to copy to clipboard in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to copy a string to the clipboard (not a region of any particular buffer, just a plain string).  It would be nice if it were also added to the kill-ring.  Here's an example:

```lisp
(copy-to-clipboard "Hello World")
```

Does this function exist?  If so, what is it called and how did you find it?  Is there also a `paste-from-clipboard` function?

I can't seem to find this stuff in the Lisp Reference Manual, so please tell me how you found it.

Comment: You may find this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You're looking for `kill-new`.

```
kill-new is a compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.

(kill-new string &optional replace yank-handler)

Make string the latest kill in the kill ring.
Set `kill-ring-yank-pointer' to point to it.
If `interprogram-cut-function' is non-nil, apply it to string.
Optional second argument replace non-nil means that string will replace
the front of the kill ring, rather than being added to the list.

Optional third arguments yank-handler controls how the string is later
inserted into a buffer; see `insert-for-yank' for details.
When a yank handler is specified, string must be non-empty (the yank
handler, if non-nil, is stored as a `yank-handler' text property on string).

When the yank handler has a non-nil PARAM element, the original string
argument is not used by `insert-for-yank'.  However, since Lisp code
may access and use elements from the kill ring directly, the string
argument should still be a "useful" string for such uses.
```

Comment: Looks very promising.  How did you find this?

Comment: I needed it myself many, many years ago.  Can't remember how I found it.

Comment: Actually, the description says it works with the kill-ring, which is an internal structure that may or may not be related to clipboard. For me in particular, `(kill-new "hello")` doesn't modify clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

I do this:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "Hello World")
  (clipboard-kill-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

That gets it on the clipboard.  If you want it on the kill-ring add a `kill-region` form also.

Comment: `copy-region-as-kill` can copy to clipboard and kill-ring in one go:

`copy-region-as-kill is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`simple.el'.

(copy-region-as-kill beg end)

Save the region as if killed, but don't kill it.
In Transient Mark mode, deactivate the mark.
If `interprogram-cut-function' is non-nil, also save the text for a window
system cut and paste.`

Answer (score 0):

The command to put your selection on the window system clipboard is `x-select-text`. You can give it a block of text to remember. So a `(buffer-substring (point) (mark))` or something should give you what you need to pass to it. In Joe's answer, you can see the interprogram-cut-function. Look that up for how to find this.

Answer (score 0):

In my .emacs file, i use this

```
(global-set-key "\C-V" 'yank)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'kill-ring-save)
```

I could not use Ctrl-C (or System-copy), but this may be enough in case old habits kick in.