# Emacs - How to keep text formatted to other editors?

Tags: emacs

I'm a beginner with emacs. Altough I'm finding it amusing and challenging, I still don't know some basic things, like, when I open a text or a piece of script wrote in another editors, emacs don't show the text formatted properly (missing all tabs, all text left-aligned) and vice-versa.
Also, when I copy a link with emacs with M-w, my clipboard is still empty and I can't paste it in a browser. I already did my "homework". I've read the tutorial and I'm almost finishing the manual and didn't see anything to address that.

tnx in advance.

Comment: Are you using Emacs in a terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some editors, like Intellij IDEA for example, will indent code based on how they understand it and not based on how it was actually indented, there's no Emacs mode that operates in the same way, not to my best knowledge. If you were using something like Eclipse or MS Visual Studio before - then you probably just have a different size of tab character (this is why some programmers insist on indenting code with spaces rather than tabs). But the width of the tab character is adjustable. In order to customize it you would:

- add in your initialization file (usually .emacs file in your `$HOME` directory, you can create one, if it is not there yet):

---

```
 ;; makes tab character as wide as four space characters
(setq default-tab-width 4)
```

- though some other major editing modes override this variable, you would need to tell what language you are dealing with to get better instructions.
- Clipboard, see this answer: [How to copy text from Emacs to another application on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360/how-to-copy-text-from-emacs-to-another-application-on-linux) if you are on Linux, then likely you need to set `x-select-enable-clipboard` to `t`.
- Aligning text to the right (or left for LTR languages) is not possible in Emacs, as far as I understand. You could align block of text, if you split it into lines and align on the line ends, but that would mean aligning by adding spaces at the beginning - something you don't really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs should work (you might need to fix the width). Use mouse to select to the clipboard, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> to cut.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming emacs has picked the right mode for the file - it usually does - you can press `C-x h` to select all, then `TAB` to indent all selected lines.  What other editors are you using, and what platform(s)?

As for the clipboard issue, some builds of emacs work correctly with the native clipboard, some don't.  You might want to investigate [CUA mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode).