# Emacs yank text to external console

Tags: emacs

When I try to copy text from Emacs buffer with `Esc-w` and try to to paste it to external console, it fails.  Why?  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you on Windows, OSX, Linux, or some other platform?  Please edit the question to add this information and suitable tags.

Comment: @blackmath your persistent terse easily google-able questions are getting really annoying.  See this question with huge numbers of upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360/how-to-copy-text-from-emacs-to-another-application-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

Try `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)`